# how to collect and aggregate logs from multiple machines in Amazon AWS environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, log-files, syslog

We have multiple Ec2 servers running and they have a tendency to be started and shut down at unpredictable times (based on load etc). What is the best way to collate and aggregate logs from them in one location?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83741/best-way-to-aggregate-multiple-log-files-from-several-servers

Comment: I was looking for similar resources myself. I found the following link where they tackled a similar problem and applied solutions with scalability as a consideration: https://www.nopsec.com/news-and-resources/blog/2014/11/26/monitoring-log-aggregation-and-you/

Answer (score 5):

Install [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) on your Ec2 image and have them transfer the logs to a central server.

Answer (score 0):

Have the server ftp or email then to you at instance startup. We have a script running that takes care of this (and some other housekeeping).

Comment: While this may fit your needs, it is not a scalable solution. In some instances logs are lost at shutdown.